# Multi-use AWS-CDK Stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, stack, aws-cdk

I have a stack that I want to deploy independent of any other stack. For this example, that will be the "NetworkStack." I would like to also deploy that stack as part of another larger stack, we'll call it "ServerStack."

In order to achieve this, I instantiate the NetworkStack with an entry in both the the bin file and an entry in the lib/ServerStack file.

This works great for my use case. However, because ServerStack is always instantiated (it too has an entry in the bin file) independent of the stack being deployed, the constructor of NetworkStack is called twice.

Is there a way to either gate the constructor so that its code only runs once or is there a way to only have one instance of the class?

Comment: Are you getting errors? Do you want 2 versions of the infrastructure that is coded in NetworkStack?

Comment: I'm not getting errors, it's just wasteful and slows down deployment. I don't want 2 versions, we have multiple stacks like the NetworkStack that can be deployed to developer accounts independent of other stacks or as part of a bundle.